# how to bind on a computed property

Tags: vuejs3, vue-component

i am using `vue3` with `options api`

as shown in the below posted code, in the `child` component, i have a computed property named `checkState`, i bind on that property in the `parent` component as shown in the code

```
<HelloWorld 
    v-model:vModelToggleClearDigitized="vModelToggleClearDigitized"
    v-bind:checkState="checkState"/>
```

what i want to achieve is, when i change `checkState` in the `parent` component in `vModelToggleClearDigitized` in the `watch` option, i want the logs in

```
computed: {
        checkState: {
            get() {
                return this.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn
            },
            set(value) {
                this.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn = value
                console.log('###value:', value)
            }
        },
}
```

in the child component to be printed

please let me know how to achive that

**link to code:

[link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-4ykuks?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue,src%2FApp.vue)

**child.vue**:

```
<template>
  <cds-toggle id="idToggleBtnClearDigitized" class="clsToggleBtnDigitizePolygon">
        <label for="toggling-digitization-of-polygon-on-and-off">
            {{ toggleBtnClearDigitizedLabel }}
        </label>
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            :value="compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn"
            @input="$emit('update:compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn', $event.target.value)"
            :disabled="isToggleBtnClearDigitizedDisabled"
            @change="onToggleBtnClearDigitizedChanged()"
            :checked="compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn"
        />
    </cds-toggle>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            state: false,
        };
    },
    props: {
        toggleBtnClearDigitizedLabel: {
            type: String,
            default: 'clear',
        },
        isToggleBtnClearDigitizedDisabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
        vModelToggleClearDigitized: {
            type: undefined,
            default:true
        },
    },
    emits: ['update:vModelToggleClearDigitized'],
    computed: {
        checkState: {
            get() {
                return this.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn
            },
            set(value) {
                this.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn = value
                console.log('###value:', value)
            }
        },
        compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn: {
            get() {
                console.log('get.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn:' + this.vModelToggleClearDigitized);
                return this.vModelToggleClearDigitized;
            },
            set(value) {
                console.log('set.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn:' + value);
                this.$emit('update:vModelToggleClearDigitized', value);
            },
        },
    },
    methods: {
        onToggleBtnClearDigitizedChanged() {
            this.state = !this.state   
            this.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn = this.state;
            this.$nextTick(() => {
                console.log('##state:' + this.state);
                console.log('##compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn:' + this.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn);
                if (this.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn == true) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn = false
                }, 3000);
            }
            });
            
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

**parent**

```
<template>
  <HelloWorld 
    v-model:vModelToggleClearDigitized="vModelToggleClearDigitized"
    v-bind:checkState="checkState"/>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      vModelToggleClearDigitized: false,
      checkState: false
    };
  },
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  watch: {
    vModelToggleClearDigitized(newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log('newVal: ', newVal);
        console.log('oldVal: ', oldVal);
        this.checkState = newVal
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a watcher in the child component to monitor changes to the vModelToggleClearDigitized prop and log them in the checkState computed property. Here's the modified child component code:

```
watch: {
    vModelToggleClearDigitized(newVal, oldVal) {
    // Log changes to vModelToggleClearDigitized in checkState computed property
    console.log('checkState updated with new value:', newVal);
    },
},
```

With this change, whenever the vModelToggleClearDigitized prop is updated in the parent component, the watcher in the child component will log the changes in the checkState computed property.

It's worth noting that in your child component, you don't need to manually define the **checkState** computed property because you are essentially duplicating the **vModelToggleClearDigitized** prop. Instead, you can directly use the **vModelToggleClearDigitized** prop in your child component where needed.

Comment: But why checkState in the child component does not get executed please?